# How to expand the product of a sequence of binomials efficiently?

Tags: algorithm

The product of the sequence of binomials reads

[image]

where {a_i} and {b_i} are coefficients in binomials.

I need to expand it to a polynomial

[image]

and use all coefficients {c_k} in the polynomial afterwards.

How to expand it efficiently? The speed has priority over the memory occupation because the expansion will be used many times.

---

**What I tried**

At present I just come up with an update scheme, which expands the polynomial right after absorbing one binomial.
This scheme needs two arrays — one for results up to i-1 and the other for results up to i.

Here is the C++ code for my naive scheme, but I think this question is irrelevant to what language is used.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  // just an example, the coefficients are actually real numbers in [0,1]
  unsigned d = 3;
  vector<double> a;
  vector<double> b;
  a.resize(d, 1); b.resize(d, 1);

  // given two arrays, a[] and b[], of length d
  vector< vector<double> > coefficients(2);
  coefficients[0].resize(d + 1);
  coefficients[1].resize(d + 1);

  if (d > 0) {
    auto &coeff = coefficients[0];    // i = 0
    coeff[0] = a[0];
    coeff[1] = b[0];
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < d; ++i) {// i : [1, d-1]
      const auto ai = a[i];
      const auto bi = b[i];
      const auto &oldCoeff = coefficients[(i-1)%2];
      auto          &coeff = coefficients[i%2];
      coeff[0] = oldCoeff[0] * ai;        // j = 0
      for (unsigned j = 1; j <= i; ++j) { // j : [1, i]
        coeff[j] = oldCoeff[j] * ai + oldCoeff[j-1] * bi;
      }
      coeff[i+1] = oldCoeff[i] * bi;      // j = i
    }
  }

  const auto &coeff = coefficients[(d-1)%2];
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < d; ++i) {
    cout << coeff[i] << "\t";
  }
  cout << coeff[d] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This looks already pretty efficient to me. If you want to consider parallelization, a hierarchical approach might be reasonable. But I think that this will not change the runtime in the sequential case.

Comment: The time complexity of your current algorithm is `T(d) = O(d^2)`. For large `d`, you could recursively partition + recombine the coefficient arrays in a "mergesort" fashion, using an efficient polynomial multiplication algorithm; e.g. Karatsuba will reduce the time complexity down to `T(d) = 2T(d/2) + O(d^[lg 3]) = O(d^1.585...)` which offers a *theoretical* improvement over "naive" multiplication.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks. What do you mean by "hierarchical approach"?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thanks. `d` is not very large — 20 on average, thus the constant before scaling is also relevant. It seems no apparent boost can be achieved without sophisticated optimisation. Then I may stick to the naive scheme.

Comment: Yes, for small `d`, stick with the current scheme: it's easier to follow and debug.  The time you spend implementing and debugging a "better" algorithm will not pay you back in execution time saved.